# Unity Remote 5 iOS Auto Rotation Stretch the Game

Tags: unity, ios, mobile

I'm using Unity to make an iOS app and have been testing it with Unity Remote 5 on a 4th gen iPad Air.

With auto-rotation enabled (the one in `Project Settings > Player`), it works fine in landscape mode (which is set to the default):

[image: landscape]

But when I rotate the iPad and it goes to portrait, the image would be compressed/stretched:

[image: Portrait]

I assume this is largely due to the fact that the game is still running in Unity Editor and the Unity Remote is merely image transmission (and monitoring touch control). But still, is there a way to make the game render in the resolution that fits the current iPad screen mode?

Comment: Have you tried changing the resolution in the Game View in the Editor?

Comment: @Kevin it has been set to `iPad Air (4th gen) 2360x1640 Landscape`, which displays correctly when the connected iPad is also in landscape mode. But when I rotate the iPad to portrait mode, the output ratio did not change accordingly, causing the game to be squeezed.

Comment: Presumably after rotating the iPad, you should change the resolution to 1640x2360 portrait in the Game view.